# Servlet couldn't receive https request in SJSAS 9.1

Tags: java, servlets, https, glassfish, request

When I deployed the web application using GlassFish 2.1 on my laptop with the "listener port" of http-listener-2 changed to 443, I can access my servlet with the URL: https://localhost/. However, when I uploaded the web app to SJSAS 9.1 and made the same change to http-listener-2, I cannot access my servlet with the URL: https://mydomain.com/.

To be more precise, when I tried to go to https://mydomain.com/, my browser still could receive the certificate from the app server but after I accepted the certificate, the page appeared to be blank. When I took a look at the server.log, it seems to me that my online servlet didn't receive any requests.

I'd be very grateful if someone could give me an advice on how I should tackle this problem.

Best regards,
James Tran

Comment: Does mydomain.com work with HTTP only?

Comment: @home: I'm sorry but I don't get what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is whether you tested if your app + server at `mydomain.com` work for HTTP only protocol (port 80). So you could verify whether it's a general problem or an SSL only problem.

Comment: I have taken a look at the configuration of my app server but I'm not sure how to check if my app or server work for HTTP only. Could you please show me how to do it?

Comment: `http-listener-1` should be configured to listen on HTTP only: `<protocol name="http-listener-1">` whereas listener 2 is configured with security enabled: `<protocol security-enabled="true" name="http-listener-2">`. Look at the port listener-1 listens to...

Comment: Hi, I have just checked it. I have 2 http-listener, the 1st one doesn't have security enabled, the 2nd one is configured with security enabled and listens on port 443.

Comment: What happens if you connect to the first one, same problem?

Comment: when I connect to the 1st one using the URL: http:// mydomain.com, no problem occurs. The problem only occurs when I try using https

Comment: looks like I can't provide further assistence. Try to post your question on serverfault.com... sorry!

Comment: @home Thanks a lot for your help though! I found out what caused the problem already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with the problem for a while, I found out that I had to restart the app server for the changes to the http listener become effective. Everything works fine now! =]